# What is the difference between net.tcp and http?

Tags: wcf, http, tcp

What is the difference between net.tcp and http?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

net.tcp: TCP based protocol. Basically it is TCP, the higher layers are "propietary".

http: HTTP based protocol - which defines a LOT more than  TCP.

At the end, HTTP is web service compatible, while TCP is efficient.

Comment: Thanks Tom..If I am right TCP is use to create Windows services and HTTP for Web Services right??

Comment: +1 It should be noted that HTTP runs on top of TCP which would explain the efficiency with one less layer.

Comment: $Qutbuddin There is no reason why a 'Web Service' couldn't be run over TCP, but what is typically done mostly to get around/throw firewalls is to run them over HTTP.

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with web or windows service. Window sservice is a way to start a program - it can easily expose web services (which is an API framework). It is more a question whether your exposed API whould be accessible as web service (which is an open standard), or used WCF internally only (both sides on WCF), in which case you can go with something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different protocols.
This is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).
This is [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

Comment: Your HTTP link should point here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: @Frank thanks for pointing that out... must have copied and pasted the wrong page :).

Comment: To add, HTTP is built upon TCP.